# Is it possible to return Jquery-ajax value into a button?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to do it this way?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $("#1click").click(function(){           //here the click1 button is executed
     var value=2;

     $.ajax({                            //here we have ajax the value to another page
     type: "POST",
     url: "test2.php",
     data:{'prop':value},
     success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      $("#into1").html(data);           //here we have taken return value into the button
    }
 });
});
$("#into1").click(function(){         //when "into1" is clicked 

       alert(("#into1").val());
      });
});

 </script>
<body>
<button  id="1click">click1</button>

<button  id="into1">click2</button>

</body>
```

now test2.php contains this code and the return value is sent back to the ajax

```
<?php
$pid=$_POST['prop'];
$cid=$pid+1;
echo $cid;
?>
```

or is there any other way to input the return value into the button

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens?

Comment: but when i press the button i am not able to get the value which we returned.

Comment: @cr7aj7: It's very unclear what you're asking. Step back and state clearly what your *end goal* is, then say what you've tried.

Comment: @cr7aj7 What's the value of 'data' ??? console.log(data)

Comment: i am trying to get a ajax returned value into a button so that when that button is pressed i should be able to use the value in jquery

Comment: if suppose the the data value is 1 then when we press the button we should be able to take that value from the button and use it. @little pig

Comment: should i add more code to it so that it is more clear.

Comment: can you do :  " alert('value :'+ data); $("#into1").html(data);  " in success function ?? and say us, what's the value ( if the alert comes)

Comment: in the success function the data value is 1 but when i press the button the value is "into1"

Comment: i have added the full code please check and tell a solution

Comment: thanks everyone found the solution....

Comment: special thanks to T.J. Crowder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments, you've talked about wanting the *value* of the button to be taken from the data, which makes me think you're looking for something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "main-ajax.php",
    data: {
        'prop': value
    }, //sending data to the ajax page
    success: function(data) {
        $("#into1").val(data); // Setting the button's value using the returned data
    }
});
```

If you have a click handler on the button, then **if** the ajax call has completed when you click the button, you can get its value:

```
$("#into1").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val(); // Or just: var val = this.value;
    // ...do something with it (and prevent the default, if the button is in
    // a form and you don't want the form submitted)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> ***"i am trying to get a ajax returned value into a button so that when
>   that button is pressed i should be able to use the value in jquery"***

Yes you can write below code but this will also change the test of button which i feel u don't want.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "main-ajax.php",
data:{'prop':value},               //sending data to the ajax page
success: function(data)
 {
$("#into1").html(data);           //pushing the returned data into the button
}
});
```

So instead of above code u can write

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "main-ajax.php",
    data: {
        'prop': value
    }, //sending data to the ajax page
    success: function(data) {
        $("#into1").val(data); // Setting the button's value using the returned data
    }
});
```

Above code will add an attribute value to the button tag and will populate that attribute with your returned data.

for getting that data anywhere in your code u can get it by following statement:

```
 $("#into1").val();
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/tb64ut3c/

```
$("#into1").html("Somre random value");
```

That code should work correctly

Comment: "works for me" is a comment, not an answer. When you have a rep >= 50, you can post comments. Until then, please just wait, the system is designed this way for a reason.

Comment: but the value is coming from an ajax page and is changing

Comment: do you get respond from the ajax?

Comment: yes i am getting the ajax response and i am stating the code in the success function but still when i press the button i am getting the button id ("into1") as the ouput

Comment: did you check the data that is being returned?